# xinetd: udp service returning just a string

Tags: service, udp, xinetd, echo

I'm using xinetd to provide a simple service, that basically only needs to return a string value.

The service is required to **support tcp and udp**.

The **tcp services** looks like this, and works as expected:

```
service simple-tcp
{
    disable         = no
    type            = UNLISTED
    id              = tcp-service
    socket_type     = stream
    port            = 20
    protocol        = tcp
    user            = nobody
    wait            = no
    server          = /bin/echo
    server_args     = Hello World.
    instances       = 25
    log_on_success  += DURATION HOST
    log_on_failure  += ATTEMPT HOST
    per_source      = 5
}
```

So I wanted to do the exact same for **udp service** but I haven't been able to make it work so far.

```
service udp-service
{
    disable         = no
    type            = UNLISTED
    id              = udp-service
    socket_type     = dgram
    port            = 25
    protocol        = udp
    user            = nobody
    wait            = yes
    server          = /bin/echo
    server_args     = Hello World.
    instances       = 25
    log_on_success  += DURATION HOST
    log_on_failure  += ATTEMPT HOST
    per_source      = 5
}
```

I realized `wait = yes` is necessary for udp. Connection gets logged if I send data to the service, but I cannot receive the response. And the log file contains "status=1" which indicates an error. But I have no clue how to narrow this down.

Could anyone explain what is going on and if there is a way to fix this, or another easy approach to just return a string via udp?

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use the standard *echo* service?

Comment: using echo would be an overhead and poses a security risk afaik (risk of getting DDOSed). plus i need the service for several ports, and i think with echo I can only bind it to port 7 (the one that is defined in /etc/services, as it uses type INTERNAL)